# MySQL- error 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> use j****
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Database setup was all right

+---------------------+
| Tables_in_j******** |
+---------------------+
| fos_user            |
| goal                |
| goal_type           |
| industry            |
| interval            |
| target              |
| user                |
+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.11 sec)

mysql> explain interval;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inter
val' at line 1
mysql>
```

I can explain all other tables, except this one.And how can i write the insert command sentence. Thanks

Comment: `interval` is a reserved keyword. Try `explain \`interval\`;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interval is a special name for MySQL.
We can't create it with normal creating sentence.

```
explain `interval`;
```

It should like this.
Thank to @ypercube